# PM2 - NestJS Multiple Instances

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, pm2

I have a NestJS application. I'm used to deploy my NodeJS application using PM2 in cluster mode (more than one instance running).

The thing is that NestJS uses Singleton pattern for it's services. I'm relying on this feature for some of my features (using a service property that can be accessed globally and holding its value).

Am I going to have issues using the PM2 cluster mode? Does NestJS can share this Singleton through the instances?

Obs: I don't want to add complexity for the project. Installing a Redis for holding the global data, for example.

Comment: You may face issues with sharing Singleton instances across multiple Node.js processes  coz each process in the cluster runs independently. However, you can run it in a load-balanced mode using pm2.

Comment: imo: i'd stay away from deploying with pm2. i've had issues with it not reporting the logs, there was an issue with the .deb package (still open). plus using node to monitor node is kinda iffy since if the issue comes from node, then you're out of luck on the reporting side. containers with a shared user defined network and a volume attached for file sharing id' say :)

Answer (score -1):

In a clustered environment with PM2, each cluster instance runs as a separate process, and they don't share memory directly.
Because NestJS services are singletons within a single process, sharing data between instances isn't straightforward.

If you rely on a singleton service within a single NestJS instance, you might face issues when using PM2 cluster mode because each instance operates independently, and changes in one instance won't be reflected in others.

To address this without adding external complexity, you might consider using in-memory caching within your NestJS application. For example, you could use a caching library like `memory-cache` or the built-in `CacheModule` provided by NestJS.
This allows you to share some data between requests within the same instance.

Let me know if that helps, Will try to update with some code as well.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Before making any more posts, please take some time to refamiliarise yourself with the site rules, including the one that [bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) so-called "AI" generated content.